# Form with dynamically generated inputs to populate an sql database

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form that the user can dynamically add a set of 3 inputs ( produit, prix, description )
The maximum is set to 10 times, so in my SQL structure I have produit0, prix0, description0 and so forth until description9. However I'm not able to populate the sql properly, only the last set of input will be inserted in the database.

Relevant part of the form:

```html
<form action="processor.php" method="post" name="form1">
    
    <!-- Dynamically ADDED -->
         
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"  name='produit[0]' placeholder="Produit">
        <input type="text" name='prix[0]' placeholder="Prix">
        <input type="text" name='description[0]' placeholder="Description">
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <button type="button" id="addInput">ADD</button>  
    
</form>
```

The script:

```html
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var maxInputs = 10; // Maximum input fields allowed
    var addButton = $("#addInput");
    var wrapper = $("#inputContainer");

    var x = 1; // Initial input field count
    
    $(addButton).click(function(e) {
    
      e.preventDefault();
      
      if (x < maxInputs) {
      
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append(
          '<div class="form-group"><input type=\'text\' name=\'produit[' + x + ']\' placeholder=\'Produit\'> <input type=\'text\' name=\'prix[' + x + ']\' placeholder=\'Prix\'> <input type=\'text\' name=\'description[' + x + ']\' placeholder=\'Description\'><a href=\'#\' class=\'removeField\'>Remove</a></div>'
        );
      }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".removeField", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent("div").remove();
      x--;
    });
}); 

</script>
```

The php Processor (relevant parts):

```php
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 

    $cie_id = $_POST['cie_id'];
    $adresse = $_POST['adresse'];
    $cont_name = $_POST['cont_name'];
    $cie_name = $_POST['cie_name'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $note_int = $_POST['note_int'];
    $note_ext = $_POST['note_ext'];
    $note_sys = $_POST['note_sys'];
    $due_date = $_POST['due_date'];    

    if(empty($cie_name)) {
        echo "<font color='red'> error  </font><br/>";
        
    } else {
        
        // Loop through the dynamic inputs using foreach
        foreach ($_POST['produit'] as $key => $produit) {
            
            $prix = $_POST['prix'][$key];
            $description = $_POST['description'][$key];

            // Construct the column names dynamically
            $produit_column = "produit" . $key;
            $prix_column = "prix" . $key;
            $description_column = "description" . $key;

            // Insert the data into the database
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO list (cie_id, cie_name, adresse, cont_name, status, $produit_column, $prix_column, $description_column, note_int, note_ext, note_sys, due_date) VALUES ('$cie_id', '$cie_name', '$adresse', '$cont_name',  '$status', '$produit', '$prix', '$description', '$note_int', '$note_ext', '$note_sys', '$due_date')");
        }

        header("Location: page.php#anyid");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should insert the record, and then update the inserted record thru the foreach loop for the multiple sets of $produit, $prix and $description fields